# How to convert Excel 2003 templates to Excel 2007 templates using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How do I built a console application that will convert all Excel 2003 templates to Excel 2007 templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Workbook.SaveAs()`, passing the file format as `XlFileFormat.XlExcel12`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I have created code as below:              Application _excelApp=new Application();                    Workbook workBook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Test\Book1.xls",
                Type.Missing, ......,Type.Missing);   workBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Test\Book2.xlsx", XlFileFormat.xlExcel12, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);                           Is this correct as I am new to excel object..